# How to display image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to display an image as many times as input(number) given by the user in html using javascript? There seem to be an error in my code,dont know how to rectify.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new element to the array.</p>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="">
<button onclick="imag(c,x)">Try it</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function imag(c,x) {
var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
var c="<img src='C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/New folder/G.jpg'/>";
    
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    arr.push(c);
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;

}
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is not working?

Comment: @Alex After i put a number in the textbox and click on 'try it' button,there is no response.Nothing is displayed. Is the code right? Logically and syntax wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.innerHTML` property takes a string.  So, you need to convert your array to a single string like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr.join("");
```

---

Note that `'C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/New folder/G.jpg'` is generally not a valid URL to refer to your image so you may need to fix that too.  You can read here to see how file URLs work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

---

And, there's no reason to pass two empty variables to your `imag()` function.  You can change this:

```
<button onclick="imag(c,x)">Try it</button>
```

to this:

```
<button onclick="imag()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Superb. It worked. Thanks. One more thing, is it possible to display a diff number below each image.Below the first image '1' then second image '2'?

Comment: @mohit - yes, that is possible.  You'd have to create the right HTML to make that display.  If, after trying to come up with the right HTML yourself, you need help with that, I'd suggest you describe the problem and what you tried in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new element to the array.</p>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="">
<button onclick="imag()">Try it</button>


<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function imag() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  var c = '\<img src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/4/11/1397210130748/Spring-Lamb.-Image-shot-2-011.jpg"\/\>';

  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    arr.push(c);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;

  }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice that I just changed `<button onclick="imag(c,x)">Try it</button>` to `<button onclick="imag()">Try it</button>`; and I switched your apostrophes here: `var c="<img src='C:/Users/Akhil/Desktop/New folder/G.jpg'/>";`

You told javascript that imag() should get two variables. but you never gave the function actual variables (and you filled them inside the function). so I removed the variables from the function's deceleration.

second thing I did was change the Quotation marks and Apostrophes since HTML standards require Quotation marks for the tags' content. switching between them allows you to keep the HTML standard.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you call `imag` function with the `c` and `x`, but the code doesn't know anything about them. That's why you get a TypeError.
You should create an event handler for the click event of the button, not this inline handler, where you can pass whatever you like at values of `x` and `c`.

Check this plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WmuAan)

And lastly, the innerHTML property takes a string (HTML or plain text). But in this case it will join all your values, comma separated, because the `toString` method of the array is invoked. Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables x and c are undefined, there is nothing in it so your code breaks. This is how parameters work, you give them a value and pass them to the function, so c becomes 'hello' and x becomes 5, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sL249wj/3/):

```
<p>Click the button to add a new element to the array.</p>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="">
<button onclick="imag('hello',5)">Try it</button>


<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript

```
function imag(c,x) {

  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    arr.push(c);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr;

}

}
```

But this is not very flexible right? So your solution is already stated in other answers. You don't pass in parameters and make the variables in the function everytime you click on the button and please **stop** using inline calls. It is really outdated, messy and unnecessary! Learn how to use eventhandlers.